# Simple Makefile reporting circular dependency -- possibly from suffix rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, circular-dependency

I'm using mingw32-make and attempting to create a simple rule to run `windres` to include an icon for a Windows executable.

The structure consists of a simple C program in `a.c`, an `a.rs` file containing only the line:

`1 ICON "a.ico"`

..the icon file itself, and the Makefile.

The Makefile:

```
CC = gcc


all: a


%.rc.o: %.rc
    windres $< $@


a: a.o a.rc.o
```

The output I get:

```
>make                      
gcc    -c -o a.o a.c
make: Circular a.rc <- a.rc.o dependency dropped.
windres a.rc a.rc.o
gcc   a.o a.rc.o   -o a
```

The output files are all created correctly, but I can't figure out how to write the .rc->.rc.o rule to get rid of the circular dependency message.  From what I can tell it is interpreting it as a [suffix rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) where `%.rc.o` indicates the rule is intended to create %.rc from %.o, thus the dependency on a %.rc is circular...

I can use `.rco` instead of `.rc.o` and it doesn't generate this error, but I prefer keeping it to the compound extension if possible.

Is there any way to create a pattern rule giving outputs with an extension of the .ext1.ext2 sort, without having it be interpreted as a suffix rule?

Comment: You've hit one of make's implicit rules for `.o` (I'm not sure which one) The easiest solution would just be to change the `%.rc.o` to have a different file type at the end such as `%.rc.out`. Another solution would be to remove all implicit rules and just write the rules yourself.

Comment: Seems like it... I ended up using .rs.obj before the answer that showed how to get around the rule, and .res is always an option as well (technically the correct one but less clear to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `make` has a built-in rule to build an executable file `foo` from an object file `foo.o`.  In your situation make matches the rule `%.rc.o` for the target `a.rc.o`.  Then it tries to find a rule that will update `a.rc` and when it looks it sees that `a.rc.o` will exist, and so it matches the rule `% : %.o`, but then realizes that it has a circular dependency for `a.rc.o : a.rc` and `a.rc : a.rc.o`.

The simplest thing to do is define an explicit rule for `a.rc` so that it won't look for a pattern rule:

```
a.rc : ;
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the built-in rule to create an executable from an object file, you can cancel it by adding:

```
%: %.o
```

with no recipe.

Comment: Welp, guess I'll have to do that or just not use .o in the name.  I end up redefining the excutable -> object file in a number of projects so this'll be a useful solution in those cases; else I'll just use like .rc.obj or acquiesce to .res...